# How is Phase Space defined in Statistical Mechanics?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, definition, phase-space

What do we mean by [Phase Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) in Statistical Mechanics. How can we define it?

Comment: Hi Kennedy, welcome to the site. It's hard to answer such broad questions like this (i.e. ones that are highly context dependent) without a bit more information.

Comment: What about the wikipedia page is unclear?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have three people A, B and C walking along an infinite straight path. One way to keep track of them is to keep a list of how far along the path each of them is, so you will have three x coordinates, xA, xB and xC each of which can vary over time. If you like, you can imagine the three coordinates as representing a point in an infinite cube formed by three axes, one axis representing the distance of A along the path, and the other two representing the distances of B and C. So now, instead of tracking the positions of three people along a single line, you can track a single point in a three dimensional space. The three dimensional space is a mathematical model, each dimension of the space representing how far along the path one of the three people is at a given moment.

You could, if you liked, imagine an n-dimensional space to keep track of the individual positions of n people along the path, which would be represented by a single point moving in the n-dimensional space.

Phase space is a similar idea- to keep track of the coordinates of n particles moving in 3 dimensional space, you have a single point moving in a 3n-dimensional mathematical space. And if you want to keep track of the momenta of the particles, you can have a 6n-dimensional mathematical space, where you use three dimensions to specify the x, y and z coordinates of a particles and another three dimensions to specify the components of the particle's momentum in the x, y and z directions.

The reason for tracking n-particles as a single point in a 6n-dimensional mathematical space is that you can define equations that govern the movement of the point, and those equations take a simpler form than if you explicitly track the particles one by one.

So phase space is simply a convenient mathematical way of representing the position and momenta of lots of particles.

Comment: That's a beautiful answer

Comment: Thank you, @kashmiri . It is lovely to have one's efforts rewarded with such a commendation!

Comment: I would be thankful if you had a look at my question here:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/702740/microstate-and-phase-space/702830#702830